# Ordered stars and bars

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of ordered $8$-tuples of nonnegative integers $x_0 < x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_7$ such that $\sum_{i=0}^{7} x_i = 99$

The above question clearly cannot be answered with the classic stars and bars, and the substitution $y_i = x_i - i$ doesn't seem to help either. I cannot see how to progress.

Answer (score 1):

Brain malfunction. You are looking for a [partition into different parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Restricted_partitions) with 7 parts of the integer 99

Answer (score 1):

We can get it by generating function for partitions (as suggested by vonbrand), which is given by

$$
G(x)=\frac{x^{28}}{{\left(1-x\right)} {\left(1-x^{2}\right)} {\left(1-x^{3}\right)}{\left(1-x^{4}\right)}{\left(1-x^{5}\right)}{\left(1-x^{6}\right)}{\left(1-x^{7}\right)} {\left(1-x^{8}\right)}}
$$

and the required answer is $$[x^{99}]G(x)=207945$$

Comment: Note to reader:  this generating function comes from letting $a_0 = 0$ and $a_i = x_{i} - x_{i-1} - 1$, so that the total sum of the $x_i$ is equal to $8a_0 + 7a_1 + 6a_2 + \cdots + 2a_6 + a_7 + 28$.

Comment: I wonder if we could do partial fractions on this.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427es9dohesqd5

Comment: @Goos : Partial fractions may not be of much use for this problem.

Comment: No, not really, but they do give you an explicit formula.

Comment: That's true, I meant to say it's difficult for this generating function.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F(m,k,b)$ be the number of strictly ordered $k$-tuples $0 \leq x_1 < \ldots < x_k \leq b$ with $\sum_{i=1}^k x_k = m$.

For $b < k-1$ these requirements are contradictory. The minimal sum of a valid $k$-tuple is $0 + 1 + \ldots + (k-1)$, which is $\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$. The maximal sum of a valid $k$-tuple is $b + (b-1) + \ldots + (b-k+1)$, which is $\frac{b(b+1) - (b-k)(b-k+1)}{2}$.

For $m = \frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ and $b \geq k-1$, there is exactly the one $k$-tuple $(0,1,\ldots,k-1)$.

It follows that $$\begin{eqnarray}
  (1)\quad& F(m,k,b) &=& 0 \quad \text{if } b < k-1 \text{ or } m < \tfrac{k(k-1)}{2} \text{ or } m > \tfrac{b(b+1) - (b-k)(b-k+1)}{2} \\
  (2)\quad& F(m,k,b) &=& 1 \quad \text{if } b \geq m \text{ and } k=1 \\
  (3)\quad& F(m,k,b) &=& 1 \quad \text{if } b \geq k-1 \text{ and } m = \tfrac{k(k-1)}{2} \text{.}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Picking a fixed $x_k \in [0,b]$ means that $x_1,\ldots,x_{k-1}$ have to be less than $x_k$, i.e. bounded by $b-1$, and that their sum has to be $m-x_k$, which yields
 $$
  F(m,k,b) = \sum_{i=0}^b F(m - i, k-1, i-1) \text{.}
$$
(The sum's range for $i$ can be reduced further, but using the conditions under which $F(m-i,k-1,i-1)$ is zero)

Now one would have to see if this recursion can be brought into an explicit form.

Comment: edit: oops never mind

Comment: @user1380792 It doesn't say that, I merely setup a recursion. Until you solve that, who knows how the result will look like...

Comment: @user1380792 I don't understand what you're trying to say. I didn't derive a closed formula for the answer, I derived a *recursion* that defines the answer. That recusion would now have to be analyzed further, so say whether the answer on your answer key is right or wrong. I suggest you look at the other answer - it seems to be much simpler.